# What is the key difference between system() and type command in console in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I checked Linux system() function source code, it will fork a child process and do

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);
```

So in this way, we can use some commands inside our code.

But what happen when we type command in the console? Will we also need fork a child process(system do the job for us)? If so, why we need fork a child process?

I have this question because I surprisingly got different results in recent project(even with popen(). popen() has seemly same results will system()).

If my questions is too complicated, any links or resources will also be appreciated.

Comment: When you type the command at the shell in the console, the shell forks and the child runs the command, more or less as shown.  You don't need to fork the process yourself in the shell; the shell does it automatically.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the reply. I mean, will system do the same thing when we typing in console? A child process is also created?

Comment: System forks a child process, and the child process uses `execlp` or thereabouts.

Comment: @MichaelPeng, I believe I provided your answer below. If I did please accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

system() is used to execute commands that you provide. Its signature is

```
 int system(const char *command); /* it is returning the address of your command*/
```

Note: you can type "man system()" in the console to read manual page of system().

When you directly type a command **[Your Operating System finds those commands because these commands are the part of OS PATH. Eg, system32 in windows, /usr/bin in Linux etc.]** in the console, you also reach to the address of the command, and then the command executes.

***Note***: Every time whatever gets executed, it forks a new process. A process has an entry point from where it gets started.

**The only difference** of calling via system() is you it gets called via a pointer. When you type command then you are accessing that command via variable reference.

**popen()**
See the manual page.
`/*man popen() */`  -- This pipes stream to/from a pipe.

The output of open is FIle. See the signature in man page.

```
 FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *type);
```

Comment: Hi Gautam, thanks for the reply! So according to your description, technically use system() should have the same results with typing command? Since I did get different results, can u kindly give some thoughts?

Comment: Will you please comment what difference result you got , and on my explanation, I would update again.

Comment: Why are you comparing them based on what you are getting output? You have the whole manual page. You read it, you understand.

Comment: Thanks! Its complicated but I will try to make it simply. I have a daemon running, and I will use system() to run a specific command reinit the whole system server in the other daemon. If I type this command in the console, everything works as I expected, but if I input exactly same command in system()/popen()/execle(), daemon will not init well, kind of like some signal blocked and will not trigger pause() inside.

Comment: I did read but its not helping, I cannot find any suspect differences. But logically if the results is different, their handling ways must have differences right?

Comment: Wow, you are researching so well. Here is the link: http://www.di.uevora.pt/~lmr/syscalls.html

Comment: System() is like an interface in Java that points the system calls inside the kernel. So when you execute via system(), you switch from user mode to kernel mode and ultimately it gets executed. Since your two daemons are two processes having their own lifecycle. Probably there is because of mode changes, you are king of getting like paused.

Comment: There are different contexts ( security permission) based on different user mode.

Comment: lol man you are mocking me. Its not interface in Java and please check [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html). And this is a library function, I don't know why you show me a link of system call, which is definitely not.  But mode switch is truly a difference, if u don't mind please add into answers, for it may also help other guys. Thanks!